# ASP MVC default route is not applying for root site url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having trouble getting ASP.net MVC to serve up the default controllers index view for the root site url `http://mysite:8080/`. All I get back is a 404 with `The resource cannot be found`. It works fine if I specify the full route path in the url : `http://mysite:8080/Default/Index`, however, I want the default route to apply even if the user doesn't specify the route path though. It seems that this should just work out of the gate. This is a fresh project from the VS2013 MVC 4 template.

I've tried both route mappings below and neither seems to work. How can this be achieved?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Root",
    "",
    new { controller = "DefaultController", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "DefaultController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to this problem. It's disappointing that the default route's defaults do not apply for the root site url though.

```
routes.Add(new Route("", new SiteRootRouteHandler("~/Default/Index")));

public class SiteRootRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    private readonly string _redirectUrl;
    public SiteRootRouteHandler(string redirectUrl)
    {
        _redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new SiteRootHandler(_redirectUrl);
    }
}

public class SiteRootHandler: IHttpHandler
{
    private readonly string _redirectUrl;
    public SiteRootHandler(string redirectUrl)
    {
        _redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.RedirectPermanent(_redirectUrl);
    }
}
```